# Read and write json data in javascript with a chrome extention?

Tags: javascript, json, database, google-chrome-extension

How can I read and write json data in javascript? I'm making a chrome extention that will read and write json and so far couldn't figure out how to do it.
I have a .json file in my chrome extention directory that I want to read and write data to

For example: If I had this code

```
    {
    "members": {
        "Thing": {
            "someValue": "1",
            "anotherValue": "2"
        }
    }
}
```

How could I read "someValue" from it?
or how could I make "anotherValue" equal to 3?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you for the comment! but is there a way to  get the .json file from a directory and read/write data to it? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NodeJS 'fs' library for writing and reading files. 
Try if this works.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var x =   
{
    "members": {
        "Thing": {
            "someValue": "1",
            "anotherValue": "2"
        },
        "secondThing":{
            "secondValue":"3",
            "anotherSecondVal":"4"
        }
    }
}


fs.writeFile('members.json', JSON.stringify(x), 'utf8', (err,data)=>{
    //callback
});

fs.readFile('members.json','utf8',(err,data)=>{
    if(data){
        console.log(JSON.parse(data))
    } else{
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

Comment: but how do i return in  a function what i get from `fs.readFile`?

Answer (score 0):

A very basic example here. The same code works in a chrome extension too.

```
var x =   
{
    "members": {
        "Thing": {
            "someValue": "1",
            "anotherValue": "2"
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(x), JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I kinda figured it out now. But how can I write it to a .json file?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, `x` is an object, `JSON.parse`ing it won't work.

Comment: Please read it again. I'm actually parsing the output of stringify